# Qt5 Tray Menu. Text disappears on hover

Tags: c++, qt5

When creating a `QMenu *trayIconMenu = new QMenu(this);` and adding menu items, the text disappears when hovering over with the mouse.

If you do not pass the parent parameter `this`, then everything works correctly. But this results in a memory leak.

The parent `QMainWindow` object is not deleted when minimized to tray.
What could be the problem?

```
QAction *viewWindow = new QAction("Развернуть окно", this);
connect(viewWindow, &QAction::triggered, this, &QWidget::showNormal);
QAction *quitAction = new QAction("Выход", this);
connect(quitAction, &QAction::triggered, this, &QCoreApplication::quit);

trayIconMenu = new QMenu; // TODO (this)?
trayIconMenu->addAction(viewWindow);
trayIconMenu->addSeparator();
trayIconMenu->addAction(quitAction);

trayIcon = new QSystemTrayIcon(this);
trayIcon->setIcon(this->style()->standardIcon(QStyle::SP_DirClosedIcon));

trayIcon->setContextMenu(trayIconMenu);
```

No focus:

[image: 1]

Focus on first QAction:

[image: 2]

Comment: I think this is not a problem of the code. I see this problem on my desktop, but not on a freshly booted xubuntu live cd. I think this is an OS issue, but am still investigating

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to check weather you set global `styleSheet` with `background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);`. It would make text disappear while only show white background.

Answer (score 0):

Found it. I tested an application in virtualbox (xubuntu 22.04). It ran fine there, but as soon I started it on the host machine (also xubuntu 22.04, passing x11 through using `ssh -X`), I saw these issues. The same as when running an application natively on the host.

I discovered, that setting the environment variable `QT_FONT_DPI` has a big effect. There is a de-facto standard of 96 DPI. It seems that values lower than 96 cause problems, while bigger values just work. This is the case even if your local system setting is different (77 DPI on my system). To check your local DPI settings, use Settings->Appearance->Fonts under xubuntu/xfce.

So, I would say the problem are some UI calculations which are made based on two different DPI constants which are mixed in a bad way. I case of problems `QT_FONT_DPI=96` always seems the best match - or something higher.

As a developer, I don't think you made something wrong with your code. I saw this issue with various QT applications which are known to work on other systems.

Here some screenshots:

```
$ QT_FONT_DPI=70 ./anki
```

[image: 70 DPI]

```
$ QT_FONT_DPI=80 ./anki
```

[image: 80 DPI]

```
$ QT_FONT_DPI=90 ./anki
```

[image: 90 DPI]

```
$ QT_FONT_DPI=100 ./anki
```

[image: 100 DPI]

```
$ QT_FONT_DPI=200 ./anki
```

[image: 200 DPI]

### Finally, I added the following to ~/.profile:

```
export QT_FONT_DPI=96
```